# ASP.NET WebForm モデルバインディング：配列の場合

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET WebForm(MVCではありません)のモデルバインディングについて、困っております。
たとえば以下のようなクラスを、FormViewを使って、双方向モデルバインディングにより編集する場合

```
public class Lover {
    public class name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Employee {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public List<Lover> lovers { get; set; }
}
```

のようなモデルの場合、

```
名前 <asp:textbox id="name" runat="server" text="<%# BindItem.name %>" />
住所 <asp:textbox id="address" runat="server" text="<%# BindItem.address %>" 
恋人１氏名 <asp:textbox id="lovers[0].name" runat="server" text="<%# BindItem.lovers[0].name %>"
恋人１年齢 <asp:textbox id="lovers[0].age" runat="server" text="<%# BindItem.lovers[1].age %>"
```

などとするとエラーが出ます。
id名、BindItemとも、配列要素は指定できないように思えました。
ASP.NET MVCでは問題ありません。

Web Formではどうやってモデルバインディングを行ったらよいのでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

`IList`の要素に直接バインドすることは出来ません。モデル側にLover1、Lover2、Lover3…のようなプロパティを追加するか、`<asp:Repeater>`等を使用することを検討してください。

なお`ID`属性に関してはデータバインド式と合わせる必要はありませんので、`lovers_0__name`のように適当な名前を指定すればよいです。